# Indent few lines in vim with a fixed amount of spaces, here : three for example, without changing vim settings

Tags: vim, indentation

I have a block that I need to indent 3 characters right.

Currently my vim has for default settings an indentation of eight characters, and I don't want to change it.

I need do to this in order to indent blocks that are sometimes under a

```
* .... 
- ...
```

For example, to have this output :

- The wished output :

  ```sh
  The ouput I'm willing to see.
  ```
- Instead of this one :

```sh
The one that isn't properly indented
```

There, keeping an indentation of eight character wouldn't word : *markdown* would not interpret the block correctly anymore.

What is the proper command to indent, let's say, the five lines from my cursor with 3 spaces ?

That makes

```
this
and this
and this
and this
and this
```

becoming :

```
   this
   and this
   and this
   and this
   and this
```

Comment: The question isn't opinion based, it responds to a use case of indenting blocks when they are under a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *so many* ways to do that…

### Method 0

1. Use `<C-v>{motion}` to select the first column of each lines in visual-block mode.
2. Prepend three spaces to the whole selection with `I   <Esc>`.

### Method 1

1. Visually select the block (the exact type of visual mode doesn't matter).
2. Do `:'<,'>norm I`   .

### Method 2

Instead of starting from visual mode, which inserts the `'<,'>` range for you, use an explicit range. In this case, it could be: `:1,5norm I`   , or `:,+4norm I`   , or any other contextually valid range.

### Method 3

Essentially the same starting point as the two methods above but with a substitution instead of `:norm`:

```
:[range]s/^/   /
```

### Method 4

1. Prepend the first line with three spaces: `I`   .
2. Move the cursor to the line below: `j` or `<Down>`.
3. Repeat the last normal mode command with `.`.
4. Etc.

In short: `I   <Esc>j.j.j.j.`.

### Method 5

A possibly more scalable variant of the above:

1. Prepend the first line with three spaces: `I`   .
2. Move the cursor to the line below: `j` or `<Down>`.
3. Visually select the remaining lines or use an explicit range to repeat the last normal mode command on the desired lines:

   ```
   :[range]norm .
   ```

And so on…

See `:help motion.txt`, the most mind-blowing part of the whole documentation, and `:help user-manual` for the easiest to follow and most comprehensive text editor tutorial ever.

Answer (score 0):

The proper commands to indent that came to my mind were `=`, `>` and `<`. The reason is that they are specifically designed to deal with indentation. For example, they can quickly shift lines, handle multiple level indentations, etc.

You can temporarily change `shiftwith`.

```
set sw=3
1,5>
set sw=8
```